# MySQL: Getting count and sum of integer values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, addition

Ok so my requirement is fairly simple. I have a table like so.

```
images     |     videos      |      reviews
--------------------------------------------------
0          |     2           |       1
4          |     5           |       0
11         |     1           |       4
0          |     1           |       7
```

I need to write a query that counts the rows in each column that is not equal to `0`, and also that gives the actual sum of the numbers in the columns. So the result will look something like this.

```
Columns        |     Counts      |      Sum
----------------------------------------------------
images         |     2           |      15
videos         |     4           |      9
reviews        |     3           |      13
```

Is this directly possible with SQL? I don't want to do the sum on the application level. So far I have written this query and it works fine, just without the sum part.

```
SELECT 'images', SUM(images != 0)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION
SELECT 'videos', SUM(videos != 0)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION
SELECT 'reviews', SUM(reviews != 0)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91;
```

Note that `SUM` in the query gives me the count of the rows, not the actual sum, as in mathematical addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT 'images' as `columns`, SUM(images <> 0) as counts, SUM(images) as `sum`
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION ALL
SELECT 'videos', SUM(videos <> 0), SUM(videos)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reviews', SUM(reviews <> 0), SUM(reviews)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91;
```

Notes:

- The SQL standard for not equals is `<>` rather than `!=` (although many databases support both).
- Use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`, to avoid the overhead of removing duplicates (which is negligible in this case).