# MySQL: Count and sum of integer values in multiple columns on two criterion

Tags: mysql, sql, count, addition

I need to do the same thing I have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435290/mysql-getting-count-and-sum-of-integer-values-in-multiple-columns). This time I want to have a result based on two criterion. So I have a table like so.

```
images     |     videos      |      reviews        |       publisherId
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0          |     2           |       1             |          91
4          |     5           |       0             |          91
11         |     1           |       4             |          12
0          |     1           |       7             |          12
2          |     1           |       9             |          12
```

I need to write a query that counts the rows in each column that is not equal to `0`, and also that gives the actual sum of the numbers in the columns and arranges the result based on the `publisherId`. So the result will look like this.

```
Columns     |     Counts(91)   |    Sum(91)  |    Counts(12)   |    Sum(12)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
images      |     1            |    4        |     2           |    13
videos      |     2            |    7        |     3           |    3
reviews     |     1            |    1        |     3           |    20
```

And the query that gives result for one `publisherId`from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435290/mysql-getting-count-and-sum-of-integer-values-in-multiple-columns/33435345#33435345) to my other question is this.

```
SELECT 'images' as `columns`, SUM(images <> 0) as counts, SUM(images) as `sum`
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION ALL
SELECT 'videos', SUM(videos <> 0), SUM(videos)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reviews', SUM(reviews <> 0), SUM(reviews)
FROM dpsreport where publisherId = 91;
```

How do I achieve this result?

Comment: This looks like exactly the same thing -- how is it different?

Comment: Look at the result. I need to have two more columns in the result, each for  the two ´publisherId´.

Comment: Numbers on the column names are the publisherId, to distingwish the reuslt..

Comment: Uh no I have no idea. I am not well versed in SQL.

Comment: Then hire someone who does.  This is not a free consulting service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Getting count and sum of integer values in multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435290/mysql-getting-count-and-sum-of-integer-values-in-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require a `join` at all.  This is just more conditional aggregation.  I will show the logic for publisher 91.  You can add two more columns yourself for 12:

```
SELECT 'images' as `columns`,
       SUM(images <> 0 and publisherid = 91) as counts_91,
       SUM(case when publisherid = 91 then images else 0 end) as sum_91
FROM dpsreport
UNION ALL
SELECT 'videos',
       SUM(videos <> 0 and publisherid = 91) as counts_91,
       SUM(case when publisherid = 91 then videos else 0 end) as sum_91
FROM dpsreport
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reviews',
       SUM(reviews <> 0 and publisherid = 91) as counts_91,
       SUM(case when publisherid = 91 then reviews else 0 end) as sum_91
FROM dpsreport;
```

As you practice the logic, it should get easier for you to figure out how to solve these problems yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for being patient. I don't have any experience with conditional aggregation in SQL. And I  have added columns for 12 as well and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'images' as `columns`, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(images <> 0), 0) as counts91, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(images), 0) as `sum91`, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(images <> 0), 0) as counts12, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(images), 0) as `sum12`
FROM dpsreport
group by publisherId 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'videos' as `columns`, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(videos<> 0), 0) as counts91, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(videos), 0) as `sum91`, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(videos<> 0), 0) as counts12, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(videos), 0) as `sum12`
FROM dpsreport
group by publisherId 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reviews' as `columns`, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(reviews<> 0), 0) as counts91, 
       IF(publisherId=91, SUM(reviews), 0) as `sum91`, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(reviews<> 0), 0) as counts12, 
       IF(publisherId=12, SUM(reviews), 0) as `sum12`
FROM dpsreport
group by publisherId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be able to handle any number of publishers, then I would suggest that rather than increasing the number of columns ad infinitum, you add an extra column for publisher id and handle the re-organization on a different level:

```
SELECT publisherId, 'images' as `columns`, SUM(images <> 0) as counts, SUM(images) as `sum`
FROM dpsreport  GROUP BY publisherId
UNION ALL
SELECT publisherId, 'videos', SUM(videos <> 0), SUM(videos)
FROM dpsreport GROUP BY publisherId
UNION ALL
SELECT publisherId, 'reviews', SUM(reviews <> 0), SUM(reviews)
FROM dpsreport GROUP BY publisherId;
```